# Changing the sizemode of a background image in picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, background-image, picturebox, image-resizing

My aim was to change the background image and set it's SizeMode as Stretch.
Tried a lot so far, any ideas?

EDIT: I am working in C# forms application. Tried simply setting size mode of bg picture:

```
picturebox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Image;
picturebox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

tried to move around it... no success...

Comment: Windows Forms? WPF? Web Forms? Silverlight?

Comment: And if you want the title to say it all, you should not prefix it with "C# Forms". That's what the tags are for.

Comment: PictureBoxSizeMode, BackgroundImageLayout are differents enums for the same purpose. .NET consistency...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at [BackgroundImageLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout.aspx).
Example:

```
whatever.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
```

Comment: You're welcome. Next time try to be a bit more specific and show what you have tried from the beginning. It makes it easier for us to help you. And that is what you want. ;)

Comment: Use this = whatever // this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;